# .NET 3.5: anonymous delegate for handlers with ref params

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, delegates, lambda

I have

```
public delegate void DocumentCompleteEventHandler(object pDisp, ref object URL)
```

Can i use lambda expression such as :

```
ie.DocumentComplete += (o, e) => {  };
```

It expression doesn't work. How should i change it for using in code? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
ie.DocumentComplete += (object o, ref object e) => {};
```

Sometimes the compiler can't figure out things through pure inference and you need to specify the labmda argument types (and modifiers.) Note that it's an all-or-nothing thing: you must given types for all arguments or not at all.

p.s. I'm waiting for a certain Mr. Skeet to hop in here and paste in an essay to steal all of my points.

Comment: @rover, ok then please mark my reply as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: You're too fast ))) I'll do it in 8 minutes